# Finding id's available in previous weeks but not in current week

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to find if an id which was present in previous weeks but not available in current week on a rolling basis. For e.g

```
Week1 has id 1,2,3,4,5
Week2 has id 3,4,5,7,8
Week3 has id 1,3,5,10,11
```

So I found out that id `1 and 2` are missing in `week 2` and id `2,4,7,8` are missing in `week 3` from previous 2 weeks But how to do this on a rolling window for a large amount of data distributed over  a period of 20+ years

Please find the sample dataset and expected output. I am expecting the output to be partitioned based on the `week_end` Date

```
Dataset

ID|WEEK_START|WEEK_END|APPEARING_DATE
7152|2015-12-27|2016-01-02|2015-12-27
8350|2015-12-27|2016-01-02|2015-12-27
7152|2015-12-27|2016-01-02|2015-12-29
4697|2015-12-27|2016-01-02|2015-12-30
7187|2015-12-27|2016-01-02|2015-01-01
8005|2015-12-27|2016-01-02|2015-12-27
8005|2015-12-27|2016-01-02|2015-12-29
6254|2016-01-03|2016-01-09|2016-01-03
7962|2016-01-03|2016-01-09|2016-01-04
3339|2016-01-03|2016-01-09|2016-01-06
7834|2016-01-03|2016-01-09|2016-01-03
7962|2016-01-03|2016-01-09|2016-01-05
7152|2016-01-03|2016-01-09|2016-01-07
8350|2016-01-03|2016-01-09|2016-01-09
2403|2016-01-10|2016-01-16|2016-01-10
0157|2016-01-10|2016-01-16|2016-01-11
2228|2016-01-10|2016-01-16|2016-01-14
4697|2016-01-10|2016-01-16|2016-01-14

Excepted Output


Partition1: WEEK_END=2016-01-02
ID|MAX(LAST_APPEARING_DATE) 
7152|2015-12-29
8350|2015-12-27
4697|2015-12-30
7187|2015-01-01
8005|2015-12-29

Partition1: WEEK_END=2016-01-09

ID|MAX(LAST_APPEARING_DATE) 
7152|2016-01-07
8350|2016-01-09
4697|2015-12-30
7187|2015-01-01
8005|2015-12-29
6254|2016-01-03
7962|2016-01-05
3339|2016-01-06
7834|2016-01-03

Partition3: WEEK_END=2016-01-10

ID|MAX(LAST_APPEARING_DATE) 
7152|2016-01-07
8350|2016-01-09
4697|2016-01-14
7187|2015-01-01
8005|2015-12-29
6254|2016-01-03
7962|2016-01-05
3339|2016-01-06
7834|2016-01-03
2403|2016-01-10
0157|2016-01-11
2228|2016-01-14
```

Comment: provide sample data with your desired output in tabular format

Comment: @Fahmi Updated with sample data and desired o/p

Comment: Please tag the database you are using.

Comment: @JimMacaulay i am using spark sql

Comment: Am asking about the database, not the framework

Comment: @JimMacaulay, I am not using any database as such. You can use normal SQL on spark Dataframe if you are aware about spark.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select ID, MAX(APPEARING_DATE) from table_name
group by ID, WEEK_END;
```

Or, including WEEK)END,

```
select ID, WEEK_END, MAX(APPEARING_DATE) from table_name
group by ID, WEEK_END;
```

Comment: This is just grouping on the week_end window. but if you see my expected output the week2 contains data from week1 and week3 contains data from week1 and 2 with no duplicate id's

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select t.*, max(week_end)
from t
group by id
having max(week_end) < '2016-01-02';
```

Adjust the date in the `having` clause for the week end that you want.

Actually, your question is a bit unclear.  I'm not sure if a *later* week end would keep the row or not.  If you want "as of" data, then include a `where` clause:

```
select t.id, max(week_end)
from t
where week_end < '2016-01-02'
group by id
having max(week_end) < '2016-01-02';
```

If you want this for a range of dates, then you can use a derived table:

```
select we.the_week_end, t.id, max(week_end)
from (select '2016-01-02' as the_week_end union all
      select '2016-01-09' as the_week_end
     ) we cross join
     t
where t.week_end < we.the_week_end
group by id, we.the_week_end
having max(t.week_end) < we.the_week_end;
```

Comment: I want this for range of date. all the rows within a week_start and week_end will be included for that period.